# SVN mixed static and commitable files

Tags: svn, static, ftp

I wish to create a repository of data-files and meta-files. The data files are huge (2Gb) binary files, while the meta-files may be text-files. The data-files will seldom (if ever) be changed.
I wanted to use SVN to serve the files and version-control commits to the meta-files, but after research I am afraid that SVN will be too slow to serve the data-files (vs. FTP).

Is there a solution for serving 'static' and 'committable' files efficiently?

Edit:
E.g. Is there a 'best-practice' or a technical way of achieving the 'hybrid' of FTP/SVN; download resource/committable repository?

Sincerely, // Rune

Comment: What in your research gave you the impression that SVN would be too slow? (Similarly, too slow by what benchmark?) In order to give you a good, folks will need to take that into account.

Comment: Yes, 'slow' is relative. My impression is based on the below sources (among others). Question updated.
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/doc/user/svn-best-practices.html
http://www.svnforum.org/threads/41798-Slow-Checkout-with-SVN-1-7-w-Tortoise